# Post controller hook does not throw 404 on unfound controller in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, controller, http-status-code-404, hook

I have a hook defined in my code igniter application to load a language based on the loaded controller.

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

/*
| -------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Hooks
| -------------------------------------------------------------------------
| This file lets you define "hooks" to extend CI without hacking the core
| files.  Please see the user guide for info:
|
|   https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/hooks.html
|
*/
$hook['post_controller_constructor'] = array(
    'class'    => 'LanguageLoader',
    'function' => 'initialize',
    'filename' => 'LanguageLoader.php',
    'filepath' => 'hooks'
);
```

This is what the LanguageLoader.php looks like

```
<?php
class LanguageLoader
{
    function initialize() {
        $ci =& get_instance();
        $class = $ci->router->class;
        $class = strtolower($class);
        $ci->load->helper('language');
        $ci->load->library('session');
        if(!$ci->session->has_userdata('language')){
            $ci->session->set_userdata('language','english');
            $ci->session->set_userdata('language_remaining','spanish');
        } 
        $ci->lang->load($class,$ci->session->userdata('language'));
        $ci->lang->load('dashboard',$ci->session->userdata('language'));
    }
}
```

The problem with this is that if i visit the URL towards a controller that does not exist, it just throws that the language file could not be found instead of throwing a 404 error. If i change the hook to pre controller, I get the 404 error as i should but the language files do not automatically load when a controller that exists is being used.

What is a preferred way to work around this? Do a check to see if the controller exists in the hook? Or is my only hope to manually load my language files?

Thanks

Comment: Try rename it so only first letter is upper case Languageloader class and file name

Comment: Have you tried other hook points?

Comment: @Tpojka yes and post controller constructor is the only one that is suitable.

Comment: @wolfgang1983 that does not help because all my language files are named in full lower case letters. I'm not sure what you mean entirely either

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/styleguide.html#file-naming

Answer (score 1):

meh, got tired of waiting and searching. Why wait, when i can write my own solution.

```
    <?php
class LanguageLoader
{
    function initialize() {
        $ci =& get_instance();
        $class = $ci->router->class;
        $class = strtolower($class);
        $ci->load->helper('language');
        $ci->load->library('session');
        if(!$ci->session->has_userdata('language')){
            $ci->session->set_userdata('language','english');
            $ci->session->set_userdata('language_remaining','spanish');
        } 
        $path = '_botadmin/language/'.$ci->session->userdata('language').'/'.$class.'_lang.php';

        if(file_exists($path)){
            $ci->lang->load($class,$ci->session->userdata('language'));
            $ci->lang->load('dashboard',$ci->session->userdata('language'));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: to make this answer even better, I suggest you add some text to explain the logic you provide...